# Do I need to be concerned with Airflow scheduler details for Google Cloud Composer?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

In Airflow scheduler, there are things like heartbeat and max_threads.
See [How to reduce airflow dag scheduling latency in production?](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#how-to-reduce-airflow-dag-scheduling-latency-in-production).

If I am using Google Cloud Composer, do I have to worry/set these values?
If not, what are the values that Google Cloud Composer uses?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the airflow config in the composer instance bucket `gs://composer_instance_bucket/airflow.cfg`. You can tune this configuration as you wish, keeping in mind that cloud composer has some [configurations blocked](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/airflow-configurations).
Also, if you go in the `Airflow UI -> Admin -> Configuration` you can see the full configuration.

Comment: i see `scheduler-scheduler_heartbeat_sec` there in the link you've provided, which means it is blocked. But is there any way to know what value they use that we are not allowed to override? So I have to start a Composer instance and check the bucket?

Comment: FYI: In my instance, the value is 5. It might be blocked because they change it depending on other conditions (e.g. machine type or load). However, this is just a speculation.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like more control/visibility of these variables, consider hosted Airflow @ Astronomer https://www.astronomer.io/cloud/ as it runs vanilla Airflow.